# geoNear not found on Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm confused as to why geoNear is not found on my mongoose model:

```
var location = { type : 'Point', coordinates : coordinates };

Shift.geoNear(location, { maxDistance : 5, spherical : true }, function(err, results, stats) {
    response.json(results);
    console.log(stats);
});

TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
 if (!(this instanceof model))
  return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
  Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
 } has no method 'geoNear'
```

Comment: Are you sure `Shift` is your model, not your schema? Eg, `ThingModel = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema);`

Comment: Yea, I can query with it e.g. Shift.find({}), etc...

Comment: Forget about the geoNear mess. Just reference this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755761/near-operator-for-geojson-point-returning-error-when-maxdistance-is-used-in-quer